# Ionic inserts unexpected class

Tags: ionic-framework

when I am writing ionic tabs [ion-tabs] then I use the class "tabs-positive tabs-icon-top"
nut when I run run it and inspect the element from Chrome I see there are some extra class the like :"tabs-top tabs-striped"

Here is my code

```js
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top">
        <!-- Home Tab -->
        <ion-tab title="Home" icon-off="ion-ios-home-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-home" href="#/tab/dash">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <!-- Man Tab -->
        <ion-tab title="Man" icon-off="ion-man" icon-on="ion-man" href="#/tab/man">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab-man"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <!-- Woman Tab -->
        <ion-tab title="Woman" icon-off="ion-woman" icon-on="ion-woman" href="#/tab/woman">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab-woman"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
```

And here is what I get in chrome

```html
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top pane tabs-top tabs-striped" nav-view="active" style="transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px);"><div class="tab-nav tabs">
```

Is there any way to avoid these unexpected Css class insertion.

Comment: Actually I want to make that tab bar at the bottom of the screen. But they stay on top.

Comment: Actually That classes are created at run time ...